# Leaflet Update markers from MySQL every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet, mapbox

currently I have created leaflet code that gets information from my database and creates a point on the map. But how would I make it so that every 5 seconds it updates the position from the database
My code is down below

I have tried using Setinterval but just couldn't get it to work since I don't wont to refresh the website but only the points

```php
<html>
<head>
  <title>A Leaflet map!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.0/mapbox.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-search.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
  <script src="leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

    <script
        src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
  <script src="Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map{ height: 100% }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
<script src="leaflet-search.js"></script>
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=privateinfo.com;dbname=FAKEINFO;charset=utf8','LOL','NOPASSWORD4U',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
$sql = 'SELECT *, x AS x, y AS y FROM GPS';

$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}
$geojson = array (
    'type'  => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features'  => array()
);
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    unset($properties['x']);
    unset($properties['y']);
    $feature = array(
        'type'  => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array(
                    $row['x'],$row['y']
                    )
            ),
        'properties' => $properties
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);

}
?>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'NOPE';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map');
    map.setView([56.413300, 8.869450], 16)
    var markerpositions;
    map.addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9'));
    L.Control.geocoder().addTo(map);
    L.marker([56.409280, 8.864608]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hydrat 1");
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
        map.addLayer(drawnItems);

        var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            edit: {
                featureGroup: drawnItems
            }
        });
        map.addControl(drawControl);
        map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;
            drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        });
        var GeoJsoninfo = <?php echo json_encode($geojson); ?>

        var markers = L.geoJSON(GeoJsoninfo, {
    onEachFeature: function(feat, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('ID: ' + feat.properties.id)
    }
}).addTo(map);

       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use AJAX, or force refresh the page every 5 seconds.

Comment: You should check out the Leaflet Realtime plugin - it's ideal for this kind of thing. Requires Ajax for fetching the data.  https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, an approach to this problem is to take all the geojson-generating code into a different PHP file, e.g. a file called `get-features.php` with just:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO(/* stuff*/);

$rs = $conn->query('SELECT *, x AS x, y AS y FROM GPS');
if (!$rs) { /* handle error */ }
$geojson = array ('type'  => 'FeatureCollection','features'  => array());
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    unset($properties['x']);
    unset($properties['y']);
    $array_push($geojson['features'], array(
        'type'  => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array($row['x'],$row['y']) ),
        'properties' => $properties )
    );
}

header('Content-Type: text/json')
echo JSON_encode($geojson);
?>
```

Then, have your JS re-request the URL for that PHP file every five secs, e.g.:

```
setInterval(function(){
    fetch('https://my-web-server/get-features.php')
      .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
      .then(function(json){ 
         /* Do something with the GeoJSON */
      });
}, 5000);
```

Or request that URL in a loop waiting five secs *between requests*, to avoid potential race conditions:

```
function requestGeoJson(){
    fetch('https://my-web-server/get-features.php')
      .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
      .then(function(json){ 
         /* Do something with the GeoJSON */
         setTimeout(requestGeoJson, 5000);
      });
};
requestGeoJson();
```

How does that play with [`L.GeoJSON`]((https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#geojson)? The naïve approach would be to [`clearLayers()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) and [`addData()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#geojson-adddata), e.g.:

```
// create an empty L.GeoJSON layer
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);

function requestGeoJson(){
    fetch('https://my-web-server/get-features.php')
      .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
      .then(function(json){ 
         geoJsonLayer.clearLayers().addData(json);

         setTimeout(requestGeoJson, 5000);
      });
};
requestGeoJson();
```

There are other approaches to make JS request stuff from webservers, such as using `$.getJSON` or `XMLHttpRequest` instead of [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). The result would be the same for your scenario.

There are, as well, other approaches to using the GeoJSON data to move markers instead of emptying and repopulating a `L.GeoJSON` instance. e.g. loop through the layers inside the `L.GeoJSON` with `eachLayer()`, then check if there's a corresponding feature inside the JSON payload (based on whatever unique ID is available) and see if the coordinates have changed.

Be aware that JS will make a HTTP(S) request to your webserver every 5(ish) seconds, making your PHP code run again with each request. Other approaches, such as using [database triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) and [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) allow for sending updates only when they're needed, just after the data has changed, providing better latency and no repeated data.

Comment: Leaflet-realtime extends `L.geoJSON` and handles the looping/updating for you (for `point`s).

Comment: Okay, but if I want something like Foreach then bind a popup to the say the specific id from the JSON it doesn't work using geoJsonLayer.clearLayers().addData(json).bindPopup('ID: ' + json.properties.id);